# Trouble Installing geoR package

Tags: r, install.packages, geor

I have just installed R and R studio (version 3.0.1) on my Xubuntu 13.10.
I want to use the `geoR` package. However, when I tried to install it, I got an error:

```
install.packages("geoR")
```

> Installing package into ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
>             (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> ...
>
> ERROR: dependency ‘RandomFields’ is not available for package ‘geoR’
>                 * removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/geoR’

so I tried to install `RandomFields`

```
install.packages("RandomFields")
```

> ...
>
> Installing package into ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’ 
>             (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>             package ‘RandomFields’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)

Can you help me what to do with it?

Comment: According to the [CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RandomFields/index.html), `RandomFields` requires R 3.0.2 or greater. So you're stuck unless you can install a more recent version of R on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get latest [R packages](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) for your Xubuntu version (Saucy Salamander).

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb..."
```

They write how to in Installation section. Then you need to upgrade to new version of R.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

It will work after that.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem installing a compiler. I have linux mint 21 and from the terminal, whit `sudo apt-get install gfortran` the install doesnt have any problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).