# can't load R package geoR because of incompatible version library version

Tags: r, geor

I installed the package `geoR` via `install.packages("geoR", dependencies = TRUE)`, which worked well. However, when loading it, I get

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘geoR’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object'
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/t    cltk.so, 10): 
  Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libtk8.6.dylib requires 
  version 11.0.0     or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I thought that I might need to update fontconfig, which I did using homebrew:

```
brew install fontconfig
```

I also re-linked it

```
brew unlink fontconfig && brew link fontconfig
```

Then, I checked the version

```
 lorenz$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib (compatibility version 8.6.0, current version 8.6.6)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
    /opt/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.2.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.2.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libXss.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
```

This looks good to me. But even with a restart, the error persists. I found other questions here on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955484/trouble-installing-geor-package) but it did not help in my case.

**Update**

I also reinstalled R 3.4.4 (and hence the R package tcltk, which is a base package) but it did not help. I am running macOs High Sierra (10.12.6).
I also reinstalled tcltk with homebrew. The installation succeeded, but I got the following message

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because tk installs some X11 headers and macOS provides an (older) Tcl/Tk.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig
```

So I am unsure what I have to do now.

Comment: What happens if you reinstall the tcltk library? (And if that fails you should post more details about your versions of R and OS (obviously OSX but not even stated or tagged.)

Comment: I will add that when I go looking for an R package named `tcltk` I only find `tcltk2`. I'm running OSX 10.11.6  "El Cap" with R 3.4.3. Nonetheless, despite being on an "end of life" box, I'm still able to load geoR without problem.

Comment: thanks @42-, I did as you suggested and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What version of Xquartz are you using?

Comment: I use the XQuartz version 2.7.8

Comment: That's several minor versions behind the one (2.7.11) I'm using.

Comment: Horray, it works now. I updated to the most recent version of XQuartz (2.7.11) and it all works now. Thanks a lot.